# What is the supported version of mysql that supports CREATE INDEX query?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to add indexes on my clients database tables but his mysql version is only 5.1.76 does this version support the CREATE INDEX query?

Comment: All of them support it, otherwise it would never have been usable.

Comment: Did you try it and get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oninboy, yes it is supported and the syntax used is,

```
CREATE [ONLINE|OFFLINE] [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_option] ...

index_col_name:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]

index_type:
    USING {BTREE | HASH}

index_option:
    KEY_BLOCK_SIZE [=] value
  | index_type
  | WITH PARSER parser_name
```

Reference link - [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/sql-syntax.html#create-index)

**But if it is not much of an issue, I'd recommend to update it to latest version.**

Comment: Hi i think upgrading from 5.1 to the latest version of mysql can cause an error on table structures on my database. i will try this. thanks! im just new on DBA.

Comment: @oninboy I understand, don't wanna mess up a functional environment. No worries, Good Luck. Hopefully, my answer helped.